# Restore scroll position of the ListView when filter is cleared

Tags: flutter

I have a **ListView** that changes depending on the filter and search query.

```dart
Consumer(
  builder: (_, ref, __) {
    final filtered = ref.watch(filteredItemProvider);
    return Scrollbar(
      thickness: 10,
      interactive: true,
      showTrackOnHover: true,
      isAlwaysShown: true,
      child: ListView.builder(
        key: const PageStorageKey('test'),
        itemCount: filtered.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, i) {
          return ProviderScope(
            overrides: [
              currentFormData.overrideWithValue(filtered[i]),
              currentFormDataIndex.overrideWithValue(i),
            ],
            child: const InventoryFormData(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

I am using riverpod and this is my provider:

```dart
final filteredItemProvider = Provider.autoDispose<List<FormData>>((ref) {
  final q = ref.watch(queryFormDataProvider);
  final data = ref.watch(formDataProvider);

  return data.asData.data.where((value) {
    return (value.anNo ?? '').toUpperCase().startsWith(q) ||
        value.description.toUpperCase().contains(q);
  }).toList();
});
```

How can I restore the **scroll position** of the **ListView** when I cleared out the search/query?

Comment: Can you try this? 
 key: ObjectKey(filtered[0]),

Comment: @JabeedAhmed Hi, thankyou for your suggestion but i cant add a key that is not constant in my `InventoryFormData` because the whole data in the list gets rebuild when i do that (because the color of the ListTile in the data changes depending on the selected data/value).

Comment: Have you tried with ScrollController() then?